# Invoke GitHub Actions workflow manually and pass parameters

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to pass some dynamic parameters and invoke my GitHub Actions workflow manually (ideally via some API). Is this possible?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

With the [`workflow_dispatch` event trigger](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-07-06-github-actions-manual-triggers-with-workflow_dispatch/), you can do the manual triggers easily.

Flow:

```
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      logLevel:
        description: 'Log level'     
        required: true
        default: 'warning'
      tags:
        description: 'Test scenario tags'
```

Manual trigger screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Blog post announcement reference, https://github.blog/changelog/2020-07-06-github-actions-manual-triggers-with-workflow_dispatch/

Comment: Thanks. How do I invoke this trigger via code / API?

Comment: That would be repository-dispatch event.

Comment: I have some example in here, https://github.com/chenrui333/github-action-test/blob/master/.github/workflows/repository-dispatch.yml

Comment: Access / use manual parameters like: `${{ github.event.inputs.logLevel }}` - since links sometimes get stale copied from first link in answer.

Comment: Full documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch

Workflows can be triggered with `gh` CLI: `gh workflow run run-tests.yml -f logLevel=warning -f tags=false`

Answer (score 19):

I think the correct answer to this is using a `repository_dispatch` NOT a `workflow_dispatch`.

Only repository dispatch allows you to trigger a workflow from an API call.

[Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event)

[Hand Holding example](https://dev.to/teamhive/triggering-github-actions-using-repository-dispatches-39d1)

**Summary:**

- URL Endpoint:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/dispatches
```

- Example cURL call:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -H "authorization: Bearer <token>" https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/dispatches -d '{"event_type": "type1","client_payload": {"key1": "Hello from CRUD"}}'
```

Comment: Wish I could upvote more than once. This is the only answer which specified that I can send "inputs" by sending "client_payload". Even the docs don't say that. Docs I'm referring to: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't the answer below show how `workflow_dispatch` *can* be triggered from the API?

Answer (score 5):

To trigger a `workflow_dispatch` via API, the documentation can be found at https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event

`POST /repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/workflows/{workflow_id}/dispatches`

where `{workflow_id}` can also be the filename of the workflow (which makes things a lot easier).

An example `curl` from the documentation:

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/actions/workflows/42/dispatches \
  -d '{"ref":"ref"}'
```

Comment: Also possible via `gh` CLI: `gh workflow run workflow-name.yml -f param1=value1 -f param2=value2`

Comment: Is there a way to create a clickable hyperlink that will dispatch a workflow? Meaning is there a way to do it from a GET without a body?